# Passing scraped page_source to PHP from Python

Tags: php, python, selenium

I've only recently started to code in Python, so I apologise in advance if this ends up to be a simple issue and I have been looking up the wrong keywords.

Essentially I am creating a scraper using python and selenium, and simply want to return the DOM to PHP so that I can manipulate the data and insert into my database. I have thus far been successful in retrieving the data in python, but my issue seems to lie with getting the result back in PHP. I get a blank result.

My code is as follows.

PHP

```
<?php
$result = exec('/usr/bin/python3 get_files.py');
print_r($result);
?>
```

Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time
import json

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))  
display.start()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('http://craiglist.com')

result = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*").get_attribute("outerHTML")

driver.quit()

print('Hello World')

print(result)
```

Now I know this is working because:

1. If I execute the python script directly, "print(result)" works perfectly.
2. If I run the PHP file, it prints out Hello World.

So the issue seems to be my understanding of how to prepare the result in python so that is can be passed to PHP.

I would very much appreciate your assistance or pointing me in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need in `selenium` if you don't have to wait for `JavaScript` execution on page. You can simply [`import requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and then get page source as `result=requests.get("http://craiglist.com").content`

Comment: @Andersson yes, that is true. I am only using craiglist as an example while I'm learning. But I wish to learn and use selenium so that I can scrape websites with JavaScript loading in the future

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not read the documentation of exec

```
$return = null;
$result = exec('/usr/bin/python3 get_files.py', $return);
print_r($result);
var_dump($return);
```

> return_var
>   If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.

Follow the exact documentation here https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution, but still get an empty result except for the Hello World "Hello Worldarray(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Hello World" }".

Comment: I ran the code on my machine and it works fine. Are you running it as a web page or as a php cli script?

Comment: I'm running it as a web page at the moment.

Comment: Add `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of your php script and try again and see if it works

Comment: I've tried that with no luck. So far the only way I can get a result back is if I loop the result in python, and individually print it. Otherwise it is just blank.

Comment: I know this is slightly off topic, but you asked whether I was running as a web page or a php script. Strange enough, exec() won't execute if I run the php script from the terminal due to security but it will happily run as a web page. Can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Mine ran fine on PHP 7 CLI